# Is it possible to apply ModelState.IsValid to just one table of a Data Entity Model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

So I currently have a view that needs an entire data entity for display purposes, but I only want to post data for one table to the controller and validate it.

```
@model MvcExample.Models.DataEntities   
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionMethod", "Controller")){
         @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <table id="setupTable">
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.DataField.Local.First().data, "Data:")</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DataField.Local.First().data, new{id="dataField"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DataField.Local.First().dataField)
                </td>
            </tr> 
<input type="submit" value="submit" />  
}
```

Is it possible to post this to an ActionMethod and use ModelState.IsValid?

```
      [ActionName("Setup")]
      [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
      [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
      public ActionResult ActionMethod(FormCollection formCollection)
      {
         if( ModelState.IsValid )
         {
            // Do Stuff
            db.SaveChanges();
         }

         var dataField= new DataField();
         db.DataField.Add( dataField);

         return View( db );
      }
```

Comment: Seems so wrong on so many levels, why not add multiple partials or create a custom object that uses properties from multiple tables?

Comment: IsValid is the property which is bounded with the model that comes from view. Now it depends if your model is linear model then it is used to validate only 1 table if it is complex then it should validate all tables in that model.

Comment: @LIUFA Already started down that path, I'm honestly just curious if this is possible or not.

Comment: @azhar_SE_nextbridge I figured as much, thanks for the straightforward answer.

Comment: It is not possible in case of composite model Dear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have these two models. The `MainModel` is your entire dataset and the `SubsetModel` is the data you need to post back to a Controller Action.

```
public class MainModel
{
   public FieldOne First {get;set}
   public FieldTwo Second {get;set}
   public FieldThree Third {get;set;}
   public FieldFour Fourth {get;set;}
}

public class SubsetModel 
{
   public FieldOne First {get;set;}
   public FieldTwo Second {get;set;}
}
```

your Controller Action can be told to just expect the SubSetModel back on post.

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(SubsetModel subset)
{
  //do something
}
```

In your View, you need to just have the relevant fields within the form, or use Javascript/JQuery to post the data back to the Controller. As long as the fields in your form has the correct names, the model binder will create the SubsetModel which your action expects

Comment: This is absolutely perfect.  Thank you so much!